# Getting "Unsupported sort property 'deletedDateTime' for 'Group'" error

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the list of deleted Azure AD groups via Graph API by using below query:

```
GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$orderBy=deletedDateTime+asc&$select=id,DisplayName,deletedDateTime
```

But I got the error like below:

> { "error": { "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery", "message":
> "Unsupported sort property 'deletedDateTime' for 'Group'.",
> "innerError": { "date": "2022-05-20T10:30:41", "request-id":
> "2884a7a0-ee08-4484-b63a-d927310c1dde", "client-request-id":
> "0ec6c500-e899-65bf-acd8-dbd786c59773" } } }

Can anyone help me with this error? I have all the required permissions,not understanding what's going wrong.

Comment: Could you confirm whether you added `ConsistencyLevel: eventual` in header or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually occurs if you missed adding required **`header`** while executing the query.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment without adding the header and got below error:***

[image]

**To resolve the error,** make sure to add header as **`ConsistencyLevel: eventual`** like below:

[image]

After adding the **`header`**  got the results successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[List deletedItems (directory objects) - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That's exactly my case, I missed adding the header. After adding that, it worked. Again thx for saving time :)